# postgresql connect to database that just created in .sql file

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to create a schema in postgresql with a sql file. I use `USE db_name` in MySQL After I created the database. Like this:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS db_name;
CREATE SCHEMA db_name;
USE db_name;
```

And After that I create the tables and tables are created in that database I'm using now. How could I do something like that in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of “connecting” to a schema, in PostgreSQL you set the search path. The search path serves two purposes:

- When accessing an unqualified database object (an object reference without an explicit schema qualification in the shape `schema.object`), it determines the order in which the schemas are searched for an object of that name.
- When creating an unqualified database object, the first schema on the search path on which the user has the `CREATE` privilege is used.

So in PostgreSQL you would use

```
SET search_path=db_name;
```

to set the schema where unqualified database objects will be created.